# If else condition not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using `if` `else` condition in jQuery to handle check boxes. 
My condition is that at least one check box is selected and after that `alert if` condition is running and not the other one. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#outer_menu').click(function() {
    var $fields = $(this).find('input[name="mychoice"]:checked');
    if (!$fields.length) {
      alert('You must check at least one box!');
      if(".a:checked "){
        $(".language").find(".translate-language").toggleClass("translate-language translate-language_show"); 
      } else if (".a_orignal:checked") {
        $(".language").find(".orignal-language_hide").toggleClass("orignal-language_hide orignal-language");  
      } else {
        alert('chose one');
      }
      return false; 
    }
  });
});
```

our else if condition is not working when if condition false

Comment: you are passing a string to the if condition which will always be truthy

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to do is to check whether the element with class `a` or `a_original` is checked, for that you need

```
if ($(".a").is(":checked ") {
    $(".language").find(".translate-language").toggleClass("translate-language translate-language_show");
} else if (".a_orignal").is(":checked") {
    $(".language").find(".orignal-language_hide").toggleClass("orignal-language_hide orignal-language");
} else {
    alert('chose one');
}
```

- use [.is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/) to check whether the element satisfies the given selector
- you need to fetch the jQuery object for the target element

Comment: I guess you should give chance to other dev to think on the problem coz everytime we see question and start thinking in that short time you put your ans :P

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line of code:

```
if(".a:checked ")
```

I believe it should be:

```
if ($(".a:checked "))
```

That might not be the end of your issues though, unless a is a class rather than you intending to select links.

Same problem here:

```
else if (".a_orignal:checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
if($(".a").is(":checked")){
```

and:

```
else if ($(".a_orignal").is(":checked")){
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.prop()` method gets the property value for the first element in the matched set.

Write:

```
if(".a").prop("checked"){
    $(".language").find(".translate-language").toggleClass("translate-language translate-language_show"); 
}
else if (".a_orignal").prop("checked"){
    $(".language").find(".orignal-language_hide").toggleClass("orignal-language_hide orignal-language");  
}
```